# m distinguishable bins, n distinguishable balls: probability of any bin containing *exactly* k balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

Assume n distinguishable balls are independently and uniformly distributed among m distinguishable bins. What is the probability that at least one bin gets exactly k balls?

This problem generalizes a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822241/n-bins-m-balls-probability-of-any-bin-containing-exactly-k-balls) which considered indistinguishable balls.

Comment: Can you show some of your efforts at solving?

Comment: Distinguishable and indistinguishable balls don't affect this question.  You are still assigning the balls randomly. Indistinguishable just means the resulting counts entirely determine the result.

Comment: This is wrong. For example, consider the number of possible outcomes. Assume m=3 n=2 . Indistinguishable balls results in 6 outcomes while distinguishable balls is 9. So for r=1, the former gets you a probability of 1/2 while for the latter it is 2/3.

Comment: I think you're assuming that for indistinguishable balls all outcomes are of equal probability, which isn't the case -  what Thomas is saying is that since the events depend on each ball and bin symmetrically, it doesn't matter whether they can be distinguished. But for example with 2 indistinguishable 6 sided dice, 7 is still the most common sum.

Comment: OK, let's try to clarify:
We have a uniform probability of alphabet size m. We draw n i.i.d. samples. What is the probability that at least on symbol appears k times?
This corresponds to distinguishable balls and for m=3, n=2 and k=1 the answer should be 2/3 (you may easily verify it with full enumeration or simulation).

Comment: The solution is given here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116426/multinomial-distribution-probability-that-at-least-one-variable-takes-a-certain